# How to use combination of enums in switch case in c#?

Tags: c#

I have following enum definition

```
public enum UploaderType
{
    BrandLogo = 0,
    ReportingLogo = 1,
    DocumentTemplate = 2,
    MModalTemplate = 3,
}
```

I have a switch case in which i want to use this enum

```
void FileUploadExceptionHandler(FileUploadControl.FileUploadExceptionType     exceptionType, FileUploadControl.UploaderType uploaderType)
{
    switch (uploaderType)
    {
        case FileUploadControl.UploaderType.DocumentTemplate:
            (this.Page as PageBase).SetMessage(string.Format(GetLocalResourceObject("FileExtensionError").ToString(), docIndentifier, formatAllowed(ucdocxUploadControl.SupportedFileTypes)), PageMessageType.ErrorMessage);
            break;
        case FileUploadControl.UploaderType.MModalTemplate:
            (this.Page as PageBase).SetMessage(string.Format(GetLocalResourceObject("FileExtensionError").ToString(), docIndentifier, formatAllowed(ucampUploadControl.SupportedFileTypes)), PageMessageType.ErrorMessage);
            break;
        case FileUploadControl.UploaderType.MModalTemplate|FileUploadControl.UploaderType.DocumentTemplate:
            (this.Page as PageBase).SetMessage(string.Format(GetLocalResourceObject("FileExtensionErrorForBoth").ToString(), formatAllowed(ucdocxUploadControl.SupportedFileTypes), formatAllowed(ucampUploadControl.SupportedFileTypes)), PageMessageType.ErrorMessage);
            break;
    }
}
```

I am trying to use combination of enum in third case but compiler complains The label 'case 3:' already occurs in this switch statement.

This enum is outside my control,so icannot use flags on it. Please suggest how to achieve this.

When i call it, i use

```
 FileUploadExceptionHandler(FileUploadControl.FileUploadExceptionType.FileExtensionNotAllowed, FileUploadControl.UploaderType.DocumentTemplate | FileUploadControl.UploaderType.MModalTemplate);
```

Comment: What are you trying to actually achieve? This isn't a flags enum, and given the values, it's not designed to be used in a combination way.

Comment: This was developed for single file upload,now i am uploading two files and in case extensions donot match, i throw a exception. When i am calling it,it doesnot give any exception however UploaderType just holds last value i.e "MModalTemplate" .Please see edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do what you want. If you were able to modify the enum you would change it to this:

```
[Flags]
public enum UploaderType
{
    None = 0,
    BrandLogo = 1,
    ReportingLogo = 2,
    DocumentTemplate = 4,
    MModalTemplate = 8,
}
```

But since you can't change it, there's not much you can do.

Answer (score 3):

You can use fall through:

```
switch(enum)
{
    case MyEnum.First:
    case MyEnum.Second:
        // something
        break;
    case MyEnum.SomeThingElse:
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Nobody suggested this yet, so it might be bad, or I may not understand the question, but I thought you can use `goto` for this:

```
switch (uploaderType)
{
    case FileUploadControl.UploaderType.DocumentTemplate:
        (this.Page as PageBase).SetMessage(string.Format(GetLocalResourceObject("FileExtensionError").ToString(), docIndentifier, formatAllowed(ucdocxUploadControl.SupportedFileTypes)), PageMessageType.ErrorMessage);
        break;
    case FileUploadControl.UploaderType.MModalTemplate:
        (this.Page as PageBase).SetMessage(string.Format(GetLocalResourceObject("FileExtensionError").ToString(), docIndentifier, formatAllowed(ucampUploadControl.SupportedFileTypes)), PageMessageType.ErrorMessage);
        goto case FileUploadControl.UploaderType.MModalTemplate;
    case FileUploadControl.UploaderType.DocumentTemplate:
        (this.Page as PageBase).SetMessage(string.Format(GetLocalResourceObject("FileExtensionErrorForBoth").ToString(), formatAllowed(ucdocxUploadControl.SupportedFileTypes), formatAllowed(ucampUploadControl.SupportedFileTypes)), PageMessageType.ErrorMessage);
        break;
}
```

Comment: You can, but it's kind of meaningless when the second command overrides the first (both being SetMessage).

Answer (score 1):

mapping to a new `enum` with flags might help.

```
[Flags]
public enum UploaderTypeNew
{
    None = 0,
    BrandLogo = 1,
    ReportingLogo = 2,
    DocumentTemplate = 4,
    MModalTemplate = 8,
}
```

map each value of the old `enum` to the new `enum` and switch on the new `enum`.

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple statements per case. You can do this:

```
case FileUploadControl.UploaderType.DocumentTemplate:
    (this.Page as PageBase).SetMessage(string.Format(GetLocalResourceObject("FileExtensionError").ToString(), docIndentifier, formatAllowed(ucdocxUploadControl.SupportedFileTypes)), PageMessageType.ErrorMessage);
    break;
case FileUploadControl.UploaderType.MModalTemplate:
    (this.Page as PageBase).SetMessage(string.Format(GetLocalResourceObject("FileExtensionError").ToString(), docIndentifier, formatAllowed(ucampUploadControl.SupportedFileTypes)), PageMessageType.ErrorMessage);
    (this.Page as PageBase).SetMessage(string.Format(GetLocalResourceObject("FileExtensionErrorForBoth").ToString(), formatAllowed(ucdocxUploadControl.SupportedFileTypes), formatAllowed(ucampUploadControl.SupportedFileTypes)), PageMessageType.ErrorMessage);
    break;
case FileUploadControl.UploaderType.DocumentTemplate:
    (this.Page as PageBase).SetMessage(string.Format(GetLocalResourceObject("FileExtensionErrorForBoth").ToString(), formatAllowed(ucdocxUploadControl.SupportedFileTypes), formatAllowed(ucampUploadControl.SupportedFileTypes)), PageMessageType.ErrorMessage);
    break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that you can't use flags,

```
(NModalTemplate | DocumentTemplate) == (2 | 3) == (3) == (NModalTemplate)
```

The last case in your switch doesn't make sense because you cannot possibly set the uploaderType to both values at the same time.